# useState dont update the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

iam trying to get some date from firebase using react naitve but iam having some problems , iam using useState to pass the array of objects in my firebase to an array in my code but the useState dont pass the array from firebase and i dont know why
this is the handleFunction of getingProducts

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const getProductHandle = async () => {
    const arr = await getProducts();
    setProducts(arr);
    console.log(arr);
    console.log(products);
  };

  useEffect(async() => {
    await getProductHandle();
  }, []);
```

and this is the FlatList iam using to show my products

```
<FlatList
        data={products}
        // numColumns={2}
        renderItem={(itemData) => {
          <productCard
            productName={itemData.item.productName}
            price={itemData.item.price}
            details={itemData.item.details}
            type={itemData.item.type}
            image={itemData.item.image}
          />;
        }}
      />
```

and this is the productCard

```
const productCard = ({ productName, price, image, details, type }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{height:300, width:300 , borderWidth:1}}>
      <Image style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={image} />
      <Text>
        {productName} {price} {details} {type}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default productCard;
```

after running the code it doesnt give me any errors and i tried to console.log the array from my firebase it return with the products in the firebase , but the products array in my useState have zero elements and i dont know how to solve this problem

[This is the output of the 2 console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG1F3.png)

Comment: The reason why the product array has data but not the one in state is because it is async. This means that setProducts may actually set the products after you log the state. What is FlatList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `renderItem` function does not return anything. Thus, the `productCard` won't be rendered.

Fix it as follows.

```js
<FlatList
        data={products}
        // numColumns={2}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
          return <productCard
            productName={item.productName}
            price={item.price}
            details={item.details}
            type={item.type}
            image={item.image}
          />;
        }}
      />
```

Comment: still the same problem , and i got errors

1) React does not recognize the `productName` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `productname` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

2) The tag <productCard> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.

3) <productCard /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass anonymous async callback to useEffect and you don't even need it,  just call the function like this.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    getProductHandle();
  }, []);
```

Plus you should check state value outside the async function because new value will be available after component re-render and not in the async function instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these codes can solve it.

```
<FlatList
        data={products}
        // numColumns={2}
        renderItem={(itemData) => ( <productCard
            productName={itemData.item.productName}
            price={itemData.item.price}
            details={itemData.item.details}
            type={itemData.item.type}
            image={itemData.item.image}
          />;
        )}
      />
```

The difference is that before  `<productCard`you have to write with parentheses or if you wanna with curly brackets, you must be write return

Comment: still giving me the same error like the comment on the previous answer

Comment: change the name from  ```<productCard/>``` to ```<ProductCard/>``` in all components